# APK Expansion Files in gradle-play-publisher

Tags: android, google-play-services, build.gradle

How can I use [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) in [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) to upload extra resources to Google play store?

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think it's been added, but there's a [request](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/58) for it.

Comment: it would be great if this feature could be supported